# Ory/Hydra exchange code to token Machine-to-Machine for tests

Tags: testing, openid-connect, ory-hydra

I have go backend where I want to add integration tests and I need an access token that user gets by completing OIDC flow.

Now Im trying to find a way to skip the Login Provider and Consent Provider and get exchange code for the access token.

For OIDC provider I use Ory Hydra that I run local with my tests to verify the token.

Is there a proper way to get the exchange code for tests?